# Two Url rewrite contradicting each other

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a two Url rule

```
RewriteRule ^/user/strategies$ /user/index.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/user/([a-zA-Z_0-9.]+)$ /user/index.html?username=$1  [NC,L]
```

You can see that they both contradict each other, what is the best possible way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have these rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/strategies$ /user/index.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z_0-9.]+)$ /user/index.html?username=$1  [NC,L]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.